# How to block users from downloading an attachment of a timed WordPress -post before article goes live?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, security, attachment, custom-fields

My current solution is to use htaccess to block the uploads archive, so visitors cannot browse them and thus see a new file before its released. Also if the client gives a hard-to-guess names to the attachments then users will not be able to get to them without knowing the exact name (right?)

.htaccess:

```
Options -Indexes
```

My questions:

1. On a scale of 1-10, how easy my current solution is to hack? Is it possible to make this solution relatively safe
2. Is there another safer solution for this? could a plugin be developed to transfer the file from a safe place when article gets released
3. Can ANY solution where the attachment is on the server/inside WordPress -uploads be a safe solution?
4. Is there a third party solution for this? Like service that could release documents at specific time

thanks!

EDIT:
Also interested in why this is not safe, and how this solution could be cracked.

Comment: This is not safe at all. The best practice for those things is to put your protected files out of public space and use a script to deliver it

Comment: Thank you. Where would the attachment be located before? Would it be a php script? Maybe a WP-plugin? Any pointing to a right direction in solving this would help tremendously!

Comment: "Where would the attachment be located before?" - another directory, not accessible from web. Then upon release, a script could copy it to `uploads` folder.

Comment: Like i said: **outside of public space**. For example, if your domain is pointing to `/some/path/public_html/` on your server then you shouldn't put your files inside of `public_html` (which prevents **direct** access to them from the web). Then, following some business logic, your script delivers (or not) protected files

Comment: Thanks! Again any articles, open source solutions or general advice ( like "hire a developer on elance to build a plugin") would be greatly appreciated.
reddit/r/web_design though this solution was at least somewhat ok, so I'm also intersted in hearing why this sucks and how this could be cracked

Comment: About your EDIT-question: this is unsafe because if you know a filename, you can still access it since `Options -Indexes` only prevents listing of directory's content. It can also be hacked, but that's another story

Comment: Justin, what if they do not know the filename, (and also it's something like 48di4kekdod9dcnckdlsdld94.pdf ?) Is then only way to hack it? I'm really interested in how difficult that would be.

Thank you very much!

Comment: That would be a little more difficult but that would still be possible

Comment: Hmm ok. I'll probably get on a search for a developer to make a plugin that moves the attachments. Thanks. And still more details on the subject are much appreciated. Like on a scale 1-10 how difficult this solution would be to hack?